# Unable to create text in tkinter python using canvas. Displays: 'int' object has no attribute 'create_text'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror, tkinter-canvas

I want to create a rectangle in which I want to display some text. Using the label function the output is very unattractive. Below attached are the corresponding snippets of the code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('817x581')
window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")

canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#66A5AD",
    height = 581,
    width = 817,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)
canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
def update_Device():
    display_Dev_ID.create_text(text="r1")

display_Dev_ID = canvas.create_rectangle(
    276.8828125000002,
    123.1220703125,
    576.8828125000002,
    183.1220703125,
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    outline="")
window.resizable(False,False)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre], because your _corresponding snippets_ can't be run, also please post the full error traceback ([edit] it in your post)

Comment: also the issue is that `.create_text` is a method of `tkinter.Canvas` so it has to be called on it, also `.create_` methods all return integers that are unique to the created objects on the canvas (IDs)

Comment: thanks @Matiiss I have tried to create a minimal example.

Comment: This code works but no text is displayed. How shall I add text on the rectangle?

Comment: use `canvas.create_text()`

Comment: Still not working, also the main file has multiple elements, so how to place.

Comment: ok, so INSTEAD of this: `display_Dev_ID.create_text(text="r1")`, You have to use: `canvas.create_text(text="r1")` (don't forget to call the function tho) oh and also provide the location: `canvas.create_text(0, 0, text='r1')` in which case You will see it in the upper right corner but only a part since it is anchored to center

Comment: also: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You want to have text centered in the middle of the rectangle:

```py
def update_device():
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.bbox(display_Dev_ID)
    canvas.create_text((x0 + x1) / 2, (y0 + y1) / 2, text="r1")
```

You have to do it like this

First of get the coords of all 4 corners of the created rectangle then simply calculate the middle point and set text there and by default `anchor='c'` so it will be centered

Don't forget to call this function tho:

```py
display_Dev_ID = canvas.create_rectangle(
    276.8828125000002,
    123.1220703125,
    576.8828125000002,
    183.1220703125,
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    outline="")

update_device()
```

somewhere like this